# Command to gray words

Tags: macros

I would like to create a macro in LaTeX to have the following effect (gray parts) on some text:

[image]

I would like to have something like `\gray{Hello}`
which puts brackets and grays the text. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: With the `xcolor` package, `\textcolor{gray}{Hello}`.  If you want parens about the gray text, then  `\textcolor{gray}{(Hello)}`.  This can be placed in a macro of course.  Here is a full MWE:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\gray#1{\textcolor{gray}{(#1)}}
\begin{document}
All writers \gray{will have to} edit their prose, but \gray{the} great.
\end{document}
`

Comment: And to put brackets, simply load the `xcolor` package, and edit @StevenB.Segletes macro as `\textcolor{gray}{(Hello)}`. You can even put in your preamble `\newcommand{\gray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{(#1)}}` and in your document use `\gray{Hello}`.

Comment: @Clément We both had the same idea...  I was editing my comment as you posted.

Comment: In any case, I would strongly recommend using a more telling command name than simply `\grey`; perhaps `\newcommand\Edit[1]{\textcolor{grey}{(#1)}}`.

Comment: The downside of `\grey`, as suggested by Sean Allred, is that, in case you later decide that the color is red while you could redefine the command, it woul look/feel much worse to see that `\gray{hello}` gives you red color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Showing three possibilities: The first as you desired, the second with better semantic and the third without an extra macro, as it is not that much to type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\gray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\newcommand\Edit[1]{\textcolor{gray}{(#1)}}


\begin{document}
``All writers \gray{(will have to)} edit their prose, but \gray{(the)} great

``All writers \Edit{will have to} edit their prose, but \Edit{the} great

``All writers \textcolor{gray}{(will have to)} edit their prose, but \textcolor{gray}{(the)} great
\end{document}
```

[image]